# How to make onclick toggleClass mutually exclusive?

Tags: javascript, toggle

I am trying to make my card selections mutually exclusive, this is the code I came up with (I am a beginner, and I am studying JS atm):
http://jsfiddle.net/4XM9A/5/

```
(function () {
    var links = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.gacca1'));
    var links2 = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.gacca2'));

    links.forEach(function (link) {
        link.addEventListener('click', function () {
            toggleClass('active', this);
        });
    });
    links2.forEach(function (link) {
        link.addEventListener('click', function () {
            toggleClass('active', this);
        });
    });
    function toggleClass(className, element) {
        element.classList.toggle(className);
    }
}());
```

As you can see, when you select card A, it shows the "card A text" on the right, when you select card B right after, it doesn't remove the ".active" class from card A. Thus both cards are active, and card B is always the one winning over.

I am trying to make so that if no cards are selected, it says - select a card.
If card A is selected - Card A block is shown on the right with relevant instructions.
If card B is selected - Card B block is shown on the right with relevant instructions.
These card selections should be mutually exclusive, so toggling one should untoggle the other one.

Comment: Since nobody said anything, I found a way to do this. Is this a good way to make it work?
http://jsfiddle.net/4XM9A/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the right idea. Basically, in your click handler function you need to make sure that the element that was clicked is the only one that gets the `active` class.

Comment: Thanks, sounds like that's a good solution, if only I was savvy enough  to be able do it that way :)
I saw you put a link, but it was a wrong one

Comment: Ya, I forgot to save the page I was working on. Here is an updated link: http://jsfiddle.net/4XM9A/7/

Comment: Thank you, I am still trying to understand everything you coded there, but I'm getting there! So basically, it retrieves a list of currently .active classes and toggles it again (by deleting it), and at the same time sets to active the clicked function? Just curious, why doesn't it disable the currently clicked-active div along with all others, it is lower in the function, therefore it should execute after setting the clicked class to active?